# Handling loads of different message-types at runtime in an elegant way

Tags: scala, generics, protocol-buffers, scalapb

In order to be able to handle large amounts of different request types I created a `.proto` file like this:

```
message Message
{
   string typeId = 1;
   bytes message = 2;
}
```

I added the `typeId` so that one knows what actual `protobuf` `bytes` represents. (Self-describing)

Now my problem is handling that different "concrete types" in an elegant way. (**Note**: All works fine if I simple use a `switch-case`-like approach!)

I thought about a solution like this:

1) Have a trait the different handlers have to implement, e.g.:

```
trait Handler[T]
{
  def handle(req: T): Any
}

object TestHandler extends Handler[Test]
{
  override def handle(req: Test): String =
  {
    s"A success, $req has been handled by TestHandler
  }
}

object OtherHandler extends Handler[Other]
{
  override def handle(req: Other): String =
  {
    s"A success, $req has been handled by OtherHandler
  }
}
```

2) provide some kind of registry to query the right handler for a given message:

```
val handlers = Map(
    Test -> TestHandler,
    Other -> OtherHandler
  )
```

3) If a request comes in it identifies itself, so we need another Mapper:

```
val reqMapper = Map(
  "Test" -> Test
  "Other" -> Other
)
```

4) If a request comes in, handle it:

```
val request ...
// Determine the requestType
val requestType = reqMapper(request.type) 
// Find the correct handler for the requestType
val handler = handlers(requestType)
// Parse the actual request
val actualRequest = requestType.parse(...) // type of actualRequest can only be Test or Other in our little example
```

Now, until here everything looks fine and dandy, but then this line breaks my whole world:

```
handler.handle(actualRequest)
```

It leads to:

> type mismatch; found : com.trueaccord.scalapb.GeneratedMessage with Product with com.trueaccord.scalapb.Message[_ >: tld.test.proto.Message.Test with tld.test.proto.Message.Other <: com.trueaccord.scalapb.GeneratedMessage with Product] with com.trueaccord.lenses.Updatable[_ >: tld.test.proto.Message.Other with tld.test.proto.Message.Test <: com.trueaccord.scalapb.GeneratedMessage with Product]{def companion: Serializable} required: _1

As far as I understand - **PLEASE CORRECT ME HERE IF AM WRONG** - the compiler cannot be sure here, that `actualRequest` is "handable" by a handler. That means it lacks the knowledge that the `actualRequest` is definitely somewhere in that `mapper` AND ALSO that there is a `handler` for it.

It's basically implicit knowledge a human would get, but the compiler cannot infer.

So, that being said, how can I overcome that situation elegantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled for this solution for now (basically thesamet's, a bit adapted for my particular use-case)

```
trait Handler[T <: GeneratedMessage with Message[T], R]
{
    implicit val cmp: GeneratedMessageCompanion[T]
    def handle(bytes: ByteString): R = {
        val msg: T = cmp.parseFrom(bytes.newInput())
        handler(msg)
    }

    def apply(t: T): R
}

object Test extends Handler[Test, String]
{
    override def apply(t: Test): String = s"$t received and handled"

    override implicit val cmp: GeneratedMessageCompanion[Test] = Test.messageCompanion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your types are lost when you use a normal Map. for eg

```
object Test{}
object Other{}
val reqMapper = Map("Test" -> Test,"Other" -> Other)
reqMapper("Test")
res0: Object = Test$@5bf0fe62 // the type is lost here and is set to java.lang.Object
```

the most idomatic way to approach this is to use pattern matching

```
request match {
  case x: Test => TestHandler(x)
  case x: Other => OtherHandler(x)
  case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("not supported")
}
```

if you still want to use Maps to store your type to handler relation consider `HMap` provided by Shapeless [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview%3A-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-maps)

> Heterogenous maps
>
> Shapeless provides a heterogenous map which supports an arbitrary
>   relation between the key type and the corresponding value type,

Comment: Yes I want to avoid pattern matching. It comes with the same maintaining cost as `switch-case`. For new types I just want to register new handlers and mappers.

Comment: @Sorona what about the HMap proposal will that work for you?

Comment: Never used `HMap` before and would prefer a pure Scala solution without additional dependency.

Answer (score 0):

One trick you can use is to capture the companion object as an implicit, and combine the parsing and handling in a single function where the type is available to the compiler:

```
case class Handler[T <: GeneratedMessage with Message[T]](handler: T => Unit)(implicit cmp: GeneratedMessageCompanion[T]) {
  def handle(bytes: ByteString): Unit = {
    val msg: T = cmp.parseFrom(bytes.newInputStream)
    handler(t)
  }
}

val handlers: Map[String, Handler[_]] = Map(
  "X" -> Handler((x: X) => Unit),
  "Y" -> Handler((x: Y) => Unit)
)

// To handle the request:
handlers(request.typeId).handle(request.message)
```

Also, take a look at `any.proto` which defines a structure very similar to your `Message`. It wouldn't solve your problem, but you can take advantage of it's `pack` and `unpack` methods.

Comment: Any is not yet available in Scala.js, but thanks, I will have a look

Comment: Line 4 should be `handler(msg)` I guess ;)